# How can resolve error for a runner to pick up this job using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

When I launch my ci everything works fine with `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` but my runners does not detect
[image]

With the value `self-hosted` my test remains at the first line waiting.

```
name: CI-CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

jobs:

  my-job:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      defaults:
        run:
          working-directory: ./frontend

      strategy:
        matrix:
          node-version: [16.x]

      steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: '**/package-lock.json'
      - name: INSTALL DEPENDENCIES
        run: npm ci
      - name: BUILDING APP
        run: npm run build --if-present
      #- name: TESTINT APP
      #- run: npm test
      - name: Build & push Docker image
        uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
        with:
        
          image: user/frontend    
          tags: latest
          registry: docker.io
          dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Comment: Is that screenshot from the runner that is installed at the repo level or org level? Additionally I assume this is running on cloud, otherwise the Ubuntu-latest would not work, correct?

Comment: Can you see the runner when you go to the repo —> settings —> actions —> runners ?? If it’s not visible there, then there is something wrong with the installation.

Comment: after deleting the runner recreate another one I have this ``` npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/ my-job/_work/ my-job/node_modules/node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node installArchSpecificPackage```

Comment: That's a new issue and thus a new question then :-)

Comment: Ok i'm goind to create new issue